# Inputting values from a for loop into a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to input values from a for loop into a matrix. The code is:

```
for(v in 1:31){
  new_num=subset(new_data, V1==l)
  folds=sample(1:K,nrow(new_num),replace = TRUE)
  for(i in 1:8){
       for(j in 1:K){
       ls.fit = glm(V3~poly(V2,i),data = new_num[folds!=j,])
  pred.ls = predict(ls.fit,newdata=subset(new_num[folds==j,],select=c(2)))
        lad.fit = rq(V3~poly(V2,i),data = new_num[folds!=j,])
      pred.lad=predict(lad.fit,newdata=subset(river_num[folds==j,],select=c(2)))
        mae.ls[j] = mean(abs(river_num$V3[folds==j]-pred.ls))
        meanmae[i] = mean(mae.ls)
        m1 = matrix(meanmae)
                  }
               }}
```

I am attempting to input values from mae.ls into the matrix m1 at every for loop from i and v loop to make m1 a 8 by 31 matrix. I need to take average values from the array mae.ls[j] hence the mean. Please suggest how to proceed.

Comment: Welcome to [so], could you show us what you have done?

Comment: i have made an array named meanmae to hold 8 values from the i loops. Now i need to find a way to do this 31 times for the v loops so that i can get the 8 by 31 matrix. pls check edited post.